# NRI for compraring competing risk prediction models - package survIDINRI

Tags: prediction, survival-analysis

I've build a competing risk regression model to predict time-to-nursing home admission in dementia patients (competing risk = death).

Now, I would like to investigate the added predictive value of a new predictor by calculating the NRI at a certain time point.

I have found the R package 'survIDINRI' which appears to be exactly for this purpose.

***Description*** Performs inference for a class of measures to compare competing risk prediction models with censored survival data. The class includes the integrated discrimination improvement index (IDI) and category-less net reclassification index (NRI).

I am trying to run function IDI.INF from this package, however the example in the package description involves a regular Cox model (without competing events). Therefore, it is unclear to me how I should indicate my 'competing event' in the 'indata' argument. I have tried coding the events like this: 0=censor, 1=event of interest, 2=competing event, but this results in error messages. When I remove the competing events, the package seems to be working.

**Can anyone tell me how I should indicate the competing event?**

I have not been able to find any example using this package in the presence of competing risks, even though the package description specifically says it can be used for this purpose.

**Any advice on how to calculate the NRI in the presence of competing risks (e.g. suggestions for other packages) will be much appreciated!**

Comment: You should post code and data that generate the error you are seeing. (You should also explain why you think that using 2 should be valid, since the help page says that event should be 1 or 0.)

Comment: After reviewing that package documentation, I have come to the tentative conclusion that the phrase "competing risk models" means that there are two models (with the same outcome) that are "competing" for strength of evidence under the statsitcal tests being used. I see no examples or references to "competing risks" in the sense of different sorts of events. I could be wrong but would ask for evidence if this is in dispute. So now I see this a a request for a search and recommendation for a package that does handle competing risks and as such should be closed by the terms of the SO help pages.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that the phrase "competing risk models" could be interpreted in a different way. I suppose you are right and I will have to find another package.